# UI Code Level Patterns?

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns

Is there a book or some other online resource that covers common code-level UI patterns (not widgets/components per se) and idioms. I'm looking for a resource that goes into some depth on MVC, event models, delegates, etc. Something in a similar vein to the POSA series would be excellent. I'm looking for something that is as platform-agnostic as possible, but I'm not sure if that even IS possible.

Comment: I've since found great links like:
http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

and

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of resources available online for Interaction Design Patterns. Pattern libraries are available from a number of sources. Check out this Wikipedia page for a list of resources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_design_pattern

Not all of them provide code-level access, however.